# Anaconda Repository

Tags: rhel, package-management, python, repository

I have a rhel server which I use as yum repository for my other servers. Now I need it to serve python packages as well. I found an anaconda repository to download packages: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/ I download all the packages with:

```
wget -A bz2  https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/ -P /path_for_packages
```

I use -A bz2 because all the packages are tar.bz2 formatted.

I also have a client machine which can't connect to the internet but can communicate with the repo server.

The aim is to install/download packages from server machine to client machine.

I have anaconda 4.5.11 in both servers. I also have the channels(The path that the client look for the packages) specified in the client machine in ".condarc" file.

```
# This is a sample .condarc file.
# It adds the r Anaconda.org channel and enables
# the show_channel_urls option.

# channel locations. These override conda defaults, i.e., conda will
# search *only* the channels listed here, in the order given.
# Use "defaults" to automatically include all default channels.
# Non-url channels will be interpreted as Anaconda.org usernames
# (this can be changed by modifying the channel_alias key; see below).
# The default is just 'defaults'.
channels:
  - http://<IP_ADDRESS>/Path/To/Packages


# Show channel URLs when displaying what is going to be downloaded
# and in 'conda list'. The default is False.
show_channel_urls: True

# For more information about this file see:
# https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html
```

When I try to use above command to install packages from the client machine:

```
conda install wget


Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 227, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 574, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        raise Response304ContentUnchanged()
    conda.core.subdir_data.Response304ContentUnchanged

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force,
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 518, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 451, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 180, in solve_final_state
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 592, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 215, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = query_all(spec)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 184, in query_all
        return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 95, in query
        self.load()
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 149, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 233, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 280, in _read_local_repdata
        _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 320, in _process_raw_repodata_str
        assert subdir == self.channel.subdir
    AssertionError

`$ /root/anaconda3/bin/conda install wget`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/root/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/root/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/root/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/root/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                     PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
                          /root/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /root/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : /root/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.15.1
         python version : 3.7.0.final.0
       base environment : /root/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : http://<IP_Address>/Path/To/Packages
                          http://<IP_Address>/Path/To/Packages
          package cache : /root/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/anaconda3/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.0 Linux/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 rhel/7.2 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]: n

No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false
```

The method that I tried:

```
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7524
```

Also I try to downgrade my anaconda version to "4.3.30".
This version brought me a new error, which is:

```
conda install anaconda
Fetching package metadata .....

CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: /root/anaconda3/envs/base .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

From this error, it says that there is no such environment of the repo server which is:

```
http://<IP_Address>/Path/To/Packages
```

I don't know if I can add the remote environment to here. I tried as it is the method to add an environment:

```
 conda  --set custom_channels.my-conda-channel http://<IP_Address>/Path/To/Package
```

But as I assumed, it can just add local paths.

Comment: FYI- This question is about the [Anaconda Data Science](https://www.anaconda.com/) platform, not the Anaconda installer framework used by RHEL and other distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda version is the problem. With the latest version, windows machine can't install the required packets from the remote repository. You need to download anaconda3-5.0.1 installer exe in order to solve this problem.